# onFling Gesture Not Working

Tags: java, android, touch-event

I have this code:
(In onCreate)

```
gestureObject = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new LearnGesture());
```

And this at the bottom of the Main Activity Script:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        this.gestureObject.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    class LearnGesture extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override

        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float veloclityX, float velocityY) {
            Log.d("OkHttp","Goody");

            if (event2.getX() > event1.getX()) {
                displayInfoDialogView();

            } else if (event2.getX() < event1.getX()) {
                displayInfoDialogView();
            }

            return true;
        }


    }
```

I want this code to make that is I sipe in any direction,

```
            displayInfoDialogView();
```

Runs.

Right now, when I swipe, nothing happens.

Comment: Ok will do. One sec.

Comment: goody isnt coming up

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: I put a Log.d in the OnTouchEvent And I get nothing.

Comment: no I dont see Goody

Comment: I am knew so be more specific and put it in an answer please.

Comment: what do you mean by "OVERRIDE"

Comment: yes. What about it.